# Como ejecutar archivo js para iterar una collecion de mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, bucles

se que es una pregunta muy generica pero esto va de concepto, no tengo claro desde que shell ejecutar cada cosa, he creado una collecion desde mongo con mongoImport y ahi puedo hacer find y buscar todo desde la shell de mongo, haciendo node file.js ejecuta linea por linea mi archivo js pero si quiero acceder a una colleccion e iterarla me dijeron que es algo como `mongo baseDeDatos Coleccion archivo.js`. si en archivo.js tengo: `db.employees.find().forEach(employee => print(JSON.stringify(employee)))`
 en el que employee es cada elemento de mi coleccion que mas debo hacer para que en la consola me haga ese print, es ejecutando `mongo baseDeDatos Coleccion archivo.js` desde QUE SHELL? desde la de mongo? desde node? no tengo los conceptos claros. Seria gran ayuda si me explicais. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Desde el shell de Mongo (Consola / Robo3T) puedes ejecutar sentencias de Javascript:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo, ejecute la sentencia anterior en Robo3T y no me devolvió resultados porque no tengo la colección y mucho menos organizada de esa forma jaja, pero el resultado fue que no hay resultados para mostrar.

No utilizo NodeJS, pero supongo que el comando anterior también se puede ejecutar desde Javascript conectandote con el servidor de MongoDB.

Saludos.